# Unsure how to use colormap with Folium marker plot

Tags: python, pandas, colormap, folium

I have a dataframe with latitude, longitude, and power percentage. I want to do something very simple but not sure how: apply a colormap to color the data points based on their percentage. So 90% is red and 100% is blue. I have created both a successful map and colormap, but not sure how to proceed next.

```py
import folium
import pandas as pd
import folium.plugins

import branca
import branca.colormap as cm

data = [
    [33.823400, -118.12194, 99.23],
    [33.823500, -118.12294, 95.23],
    [33.823600, -118.12394, 91.23],
    [33.823700, -118.12494, 90.00]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['latitude','longitude','power'])

x_start = (df['latitude'].max() + df['latitude'].min()) / 2
y_start = (df['longitude'].max() + df['longitude'].min()) / 2
start_coord = (x_start, y_start)

map = folium.Map(location=start_coord, zoom_start=12)

lat = list(df.latitude)
lon = list(df.longitude)

for loc in zip(lat, lon):
    folium.Circle(
        location=loc,
        radius=10,
        #fill=True,
        #color='blue',
        #fill_opacity=0.7
    ).add_to(map)

display(map)

colormap = cm.LinearColormap(colors=['red','lightblue'], index=[90,100],vmin=90,vmax=100)
colormap
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm in a rush, but this is how I've done it in the past.  Create the CM and then call it like so `colormap(.9)`

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import folium.plugins

import branca
import branca.colormap as cm

data = [
    [33.823400, -118.12194, 99.23],
    [33.823500, -118.12294, 95.23],
    [33.823600, -118.12394, 91.23],
    [33.823700, -118.12494, 90.00]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['latitude','longitude','power'])

x_start = (df['latitude'].max() + df['latitude'].min()) / 2
y_start = (df['longitude'].max() + df['longitude'].min()) / 2
start_coord = (x_start, y_start)


colormap = cm.LinearColormap(colors=['red','lightblue'], index=[90,100],vmin=90,vmax=100)

map = folium.Map(location=start_coord, zoom_start=12)


lat = list(df.latitude)
lon = list(df.longitude)
pow = list(df.power)


for loc, p in zip(zip(lat, lon), pow):
    folium.Circle(
        location=loc,
        radius=10,
        fill=True,
        color=colormap(p),
        #fill_opacity=0.7
    ).add_to(map)

map.add_child(colormap)

display(map)
```

[image: Map with colour bar]

Comment: Revisiting this, I noticed I forgot to mark this as correct. Your solution has helped me out, thank you.