# Trying to show data for yearly salary in US States, but Folium Choropleth map only showing grey

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter-notebook, folium

I'm trying to show the 'total_yearly_compensation' and 'base_salary' for tech jobs within the United States. I've been working on this for awhile and can't seem to find why the US-States map only is grey instead of the colors it should be showing. My code is below.

**Here is all of the imports that I'm bringing in and a glimpse of my CSV file:**
[image: Imports screenshot]

**Here is a screenshot of what my us-states.json file looks like:**
[image: us-states.json screenshot]

**And this is how I'm trying to create the Folium Choropleth map (also showing the grey US map):**
[image: Screenshot of code to create map]

I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876620/unsure-how-to-use-colormap-with-folium-marker-plot]

Comment: Sorry, that's not useful for this. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the name of the location column in the parameter `columns` of the `Choropleth()` function. Moreover, you need to have exactly the same values in the location column and in the JSON file (you can create an `id` column from the `location` column). You can update your code like that :

```py
df_sal[["city", "id"]] = df_sal["location"].str.split(", ", expand=True)
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = country_geo,
    data = data_to_plot,
    columns = ['id', 'total_yearly_compensation', 'base_salary'],
    key_on = 'feature.id',
).add_to(map)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is super helpful and I think I'm headed in the right direction. Unfortunately, I'm still getting a grey map. I split the 'city' and 'state' in my csv file, so it's no longer called 'location' and made it two separate columns. Now I'm not sure what to do after that. I really appreciate your help as I am pretty new with this

Comment: I am quite sure it is due to a mismatch between the names of the states : check the case (lower or uppercase) and whitespace (at the beginning or at the end)

Comment: You were absolutely correct! Thanks you so much!!!