# How to use a custom colour (color) ramp on a folium Choropleth Map

Tags: python, leaflet, maps, folium

I would like to add a custom colour ramp to my Folium Choropleth Map however when i crate a color ramp/ map using `branca` it outputs a class which is not accepted by the `fill_color` variable of `folium.Choropleth` as it is a class and not a string.

In this code I create a colour map using `from branca.colormap import StepColormap`

```
# Defining variables
max_value = df[status].max()
hex_codes = ['#0b0405', '#28192e', '#3b2e5d', '#40498e', '#366a9f', '#348ba6', '#38aaac', '#55caad', '#a1dfb9', '#def5e5']

# creating the custom ramp
custom_colour_map = StepColormap(colors = hex_codes, vmin = 0, vmax = df[status].max(), tick_labels=[0, max_value*.25, max_value*.5, max_value*.75, max_value])
```

I then create a folium map and below is the code for the Choropleth section.

```
folium.Choropleth(
        geo_data=df,
        data=df,
        bins = [0,10,100, 1000, 10000],
        columns=('polyname', status),
        key_on="feature.properties.polyname",
        fill_color = custom_colour_map,
        legend_name=status
    ).add_to(m)
```

However I get a an error that the fill_color is expecting a string but got a class. I have also tried using `custom_colour_map.colors` without any luck.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This section of folium doc on "[Using colormaps](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/advanced_guide/colormaps.html)" has the answer you are looking for.

Basically, you need to Step Color map using `StepColormap` in `folium.colormap`. So using you hex code, your color map looks like this *(Note: I used arbitrary numbers since I don't have your exact dataframe values)*:-

```
# creating the custom ramp
hex_codes = ['#0b0405', '#28192e', '#3b2e5d', '#40498e', '#366a9f', '#348ba6', '#38aaac', '#55caad', '#a1dfb9', '#def5e5']
custom_colour_map = cm.StepColormap(colors = hex_codes, vmin = 0, vmax = 10, tick_labels=[0, 4, 6, 8, 10])
```

[image]

Here is a complete reproducible code snippet:-

```
import json
import folium
import requests
import pandas as pd
import branca.colormap as cm

# Read JSON and CSV file provided on folium github page...
geo_json_data = requests.get( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium-example-data/main/us_states.json").json()
unemployment = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium-example-data/main/us_unemployment_oct_2012.csv")
unemployment_dict = unemployment.set_index("State")["Unemployment"]


# Creating the custom ramp
hex_codes = ['#0b0405', '#28192e', '#3b2e5d', '#40498e', '#366a9f', '#348ba6', '#38aaac', '#55caad', '#a1dfb9', '#def5e5']
custom_colour_map = cm.StepColormap(colors = hex_codes, vmin = 0, vmax = 10, tick_labels=[0, 4, 6, 8, 10], caption="Custom Colour Map")


# Create the map....
m = folium.Map([43,-100], tiles='cartodbpositron', zoom_start=4, 
               attr="<a href=https://endless-sky.github.io/>Endless Sky</a>")

folium.GeoJson(
    geo_json_data,
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        'fillColor': custom_colour_map(unemployment_dict[feature['id']]),
        'color' : 'black',
        'weight' : 2,
        'dashArray' : '5, 5'
        }
    ).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

This SO question has basic a good answer that will help you: [Unsure how to use colormap with Folium marker plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876620/unsure-how-to-use-colormap-with-folium-marker-plot)